# List mapping manually

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem when our database gets updated by adding a new property/column.

My first step is to update my POCO. in this example "NewProp". the first time I call or read from the database it will return an error "nullable object must return a value". because my classes are expecting "NewProp" from the database...

My solution is update each document to include "NewProp".. and then I wrote a script that iterates each row. mapping manually(some kind of ignoring) the "new" property, like this:

```
var items = await _context.Student
                 .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                 .Select(x => new Domain.Entities.Student
                 {
                     Id = x.Id,
                     ProfId = x.ProfId,
                     NewProp = 0
                 )
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

then iterate thru items and update each row to add a default value to NewProp.

Now my problem is when a new property is inside a list.. in this example a new prop inside the list.

Question: how to manually project the Subject?

Here's my classes

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProfId { get; set; }
    public List<SubjectDTO> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NewProp { get; set; } //Error mapping this
}


var items = await _context.Student
                     .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted)
                     .Select(x => new Domain.Entities.Student
                     {
                         Id = x.Id,
                         ProfId = x.ProfId,

                         //I dont know how to map or project manually
                         Subjects = x.Subjects.Select(z =>
                             new List<Subject>
                             {
                                new Subject
                                {
                                  Id = "test", // how to get value
                                  Name = "abc", // how to get value
                                  NewProp = 100,
                                }
                             }
                         )
                     )
                     .AsNoTracking()
                     .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Im using cosmosDB by the way.

EDIT error below

```
var items = await _context.Student
                  .Select(x => new Domain.Entities.Student
                  {
                       id = x.id,
                       ProfId = x.ProfId,
                       Subjects = x.Subjects.Select(z => new Subject
                       {
                           id = z.id,
                           Name = z.Name,
                           NewProp = 0
                       }).ToList()
                    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken); 

System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
```

at lambda_method29(Closure , JObject , Int32 )
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 selector)+MoveNext()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.CosmosProjectionBindingRemovingExpressionVisitor.PopulateCollection[TEntity,TCollection](IClrCollectionAccessor accessor, IEnumerable`1 entities) at lambda_method28(Closure , QueryContext , JObject ) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: What error are you getting? Also why do you create a list of `Subject` not just `Subject` in your select statement?

Comment: @GuruStron after the suggestion by Timur I thought I already solved the issue. Because thats what I thought, byu mapping manually there will be no error. Im getting "nullable object must have a value" due to that missing database column

Comment: This should actually work. I will try to reproduce it now

Comment: @TimurUmerov i updated the queston and posted the error above. thanks

Comment: @samantha07 Can you please update with the new code you are currently using?

Comment: @TimurUmerov please see updated code

Comment: Is this code working without the "NewProp" mapping?

Comment: @TimurUmerov even if i removed it still not working and showing the same error. the error will be gone if i Updated the document from cosmosdb. thank you for your patience

Comment: @TimurUmerov see this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68060075/cosmosdb-ef-returning-nullable-object-must-have-a-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your are looking for?

```
.Select(x => new Domain.Entities.Student
{
     Id = x.Id,
     ProfId = x.ProfId,
     Subjects = x.Subjects.Select(z => new Subject
     {
         Id = z.Id,
         Name = z.Name,
         // map other properties
     }).ToList()
}).AsNoTracking() 
.ToListAsync()
```

You don't actually need to call `AsNoTracking()`, since you use a projection. Projection based results are not tracked by the context

Comment: You are correct. thank you. I spent more time than I should be on this problem of mine. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Hmm im still getting "nullable object must have a value" any idea? I already mapped it manually