# CosmosDb / EF returning Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.1

I was given an instruction to add a new property "Subjects.NewProp" for our classes, see below:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProfId { get; set; }
    public List<SubjectDTO> Subjects { get; set; }
}

public class SubjectDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NewProp { get; set; } //NEW 
}
```

Cosmos document:

```
{
    "Id ": "b22d7cef-8736-4d21-983d-0939adb875d2",
    "ProfId ": "541553a2-2f4e-473f-9a93-21d6c440a4a1",
    "Subjects": [
        {
            "Id": "6cf08251-6e99-4b43-83ae-90ba4d229879",
            "Name": "Test"
    },
    {
            "Id": "889c85e3-6799-4e8b-9c58-b06cf2de3b50",
            "Name": "Test",
            "NewProp": 123,     
    }]
}
```

Im getting error for the rows that the "NewProp" is missing. As a workaround, I thought projection will solve the issue because basically youre ignoring it and setting all values to 0. Here's what my query looks like:

```
var items = await _context.Student
              .Select(x => new Domain.Entities.Student
              {
                   Id = x.Id,
                   ProfId = x.ProfId,
                   Subjects = x.Subjects.Select(z => new Subject
                   {
                       Id= z.Id,
                       Name = z.Name,
                       NewProp = 0 //NEW
                   }).ToList()
                }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken); 



System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
at lambda_method29(Closure , JObject , Int32 ) at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable1 source, Func3 selector)+MoveNext() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.
```

CosmosProjectionBindingRemovingExpressionVisitor.PopulateCollection[TEntity,TCollection](IClrCollectionAccessor accessor, IEnumerable1 entities) at lambda_method28(Closure ,
QueryContext , JObject ) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.
QueryingEnumerable1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource]
(IQueryable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource]
(IQueryable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Can you check the actual query that's being generated by the EF?

Comment: There is a chance, that somehow database returns you a `null` with the query generated by EF, and then it tries to map that to a non-nullable property e.g. `NewProp` which is `int`. To verify that's not the case, you can change `NewProp`'s datatype to `int?` and see if that's working